# UWP Template Control with Caliburn.Micro Binding , How?

Tags: uwp, caliburn.micro

I am making a TempleteControl with Calibrun.Micro. 
To make problem simpler, I re-make my TempleteControl with only 2 x TextBlock cont.

**Problem**

One TextBlock is binding as "TemplateBinding". It works fine.
I want to use Calibrun.Micro Binding for 2nd TextBlock. but I have no idea how to write it..

```
<TextBlock x:Name="PART_Title" Text="{TemplateBinding Title_Text}" TextAlignment="Center" />
<TextBlock x:Name="PART_Title2" Text="{Binding Title_Text2}" TextAlignment="Center" />
```

Now, My code has error at ".Set" method.

```
public string Title_Text2 {
        get { return _title_Text2; }
        set { this.Set(_title_Text2); }
}
```

Is there any way to use Caliburn.Micro binding in TemplateControl UWP ?

[Here is full project code in GitHub.](https://github.com/bidasknakayama/CaliburnMicroCustomControl2)

Please give me your idea that I can start to learn...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *always* use a dependency property inside a custom control if you want it to be bindable and animatable.

Your `Title_Text2` should be defined just like `Title_Text`. I haven't used *Caliburn.Micro* before but the `Set` method could be their method to notify property changes in a *ViewModel*. Inside a control, you shouldn't be doing this.

---

### Update

Actually what you commented out in your code is almost correct. You can obtain a reference of that `TextBlock` and update its `Text` internally.

```
private TextBlock _titleTextBlock;
protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();

    _titleTextBlock = GetTemplateChild(TitlePart2Name) as TextBlock;
    if (_titleTextBlock != null)
    {
        _titleTextBlock.Text = "ByeBye by GetTemplateChild";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Justin many times : )  ...Title_Text2, I do not want to use it as a  DependencyProperty. because it is internal value.  but I want to update the value from Class...................

Comment: Your welcome as always. :) Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Wow. I understand All, In Templete Control, We should use DependencyProperty or We should find a Property with GetTemplateChild !

Comment: Yeah you use dependency property to expose public property APIs for others to use; you use `GetTemplateChild` to find controls/panels/shapes defined inside your custom control's `ControlTemplate` to interact with them internally.